# Noise and interference from a buck converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, zigbee

I have heard that buck converters cause noise/radio interference. Since I am using it next to a Xbee S2C module, will it interfere with my Zigbee signal?

Comment: It might. You'll find out when you're testing.

Comment: some cars are loud. will a car wake my baby? it depends of course.